# Complicated request from the void - one table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a steps table. It describes the steps a person takes towards a specific goal. For example, 3 steps to one goal, 5 steps to the second. And every time I take a new step, I write a new step into this table. Question: how can I determine, for example, whether step No. X has been made? The given record can and not exist?
For example, I have 2 steps out of 3 recorded, and for example I want to select all records that do not have step number 3

Example:

```
id, name, step

1 Mark 1
2 Mark 2
3 Mark 3

4, Jenny, 1
5, Jenny, 2

6, Tony, 1
7, Tony, 2
8, Tony, 3

9, Joe, 1
```

For example, I want to show everyone who does not have step number 3
How can I do it?

Comment: `select name from steps group by name having sum(step=3)=0`

Comment: How do you know this? `I have 2 steps out of 3 recorded` Do you have a Goals table where each Goal_ID has a determined number of steps to complete?

Comment: The number of steps is constantly different. I need to know exactly. For example, show all steps where = 2. But what if someone took, for example, one step? I want to get these guys who took one step instead of one. in my example, it should be that there is no Jennny -3, and Joe - 2 and Joe - 3 That's what I should get as a result

Comment: I have a table structure like this. Since there can be a different number of steps. I need to determine exactly what step, for example, at number 2, Joe did not do.